# Eloquent ORM returning collection with single item

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Using Laravel 4.2 and eloquent ORM, I know that all multi-result sets returned by a query will return a Collection object, as documented here (http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections).

I am running a query that returns a single object:

```
$faq = ProductFaq::where($where)->with('products')->get();
```

However, I'm being returned a collection.

In order to use the result do I need to chain `->first()` to the end of my statement? I'm just confused if the docs are saying that every call that uses `get()` will return a collection, or only `get()` calls that have multiple results.

Comment: `get()` returns a collection of objects, `first()` return a single object (the first row).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Get* returns a Collection instance, you should call *first* **instead** of the *get* method

```
 $faq = ProductFaq::where($where)->with('products')->first();
```